# Gmail OAuth from within docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, gmail, gmail-api

I have various backend services running in containers. I am writing a microservice to handle the sending of emails.

My email provider for business emails is GSuite (Gmail).

I've been reading the following [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)

This all seems well and good but it requires human intervention in order to authorise the application to send emails.

I need this to be fully autonomous in that whenever the container starts up it requests access tokens and authorises itself.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find any literature to help

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution to this and thought I would post it just incase anyone else stumbles across this problem.

The answer to accessing the GMAIL API with no human intervention is `service accounts`.

Service accounts can impersonate authenticated users. So for instance I now have a service account sending emails as if they are coming from `michael@mydomainname.com`

I basically followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243862/send-mail-via-google-apps-gmail-using-service-account-domain-wide-delegation-in)

There are a few other steps to setting up service accounts that can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

I hope this helps someone.