# Google Suite - Google API access - Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I am struggling for days with the set up in trying to access GMail Google API from a node.js script using googleapis lib. I succeeded once but I cannot remember how I did it , I tried to reset a project, service-account and G-Suite Domain wide delegation following the Google doc ..

Here is what I did :

In my GCP Console console, 
1. Existing organisation : lechorodescharentes.org
2. In this organisation , I created a project : choro-dev
3. In this project I created a service account : choro-dev-postoffice
    with choro-dev-postoffice with role TokenGenerator
    and enabled the Google Apps Domain-wid Delegation
    downloaded the new private key ( JSON file )
4.  I enabled the GMail API ( from Libray menu)

In my G-Suite domain's admin console, 
5. I added the following copes for this service account's ClientID
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"

6. Node.js client
   I am trying to access the GMail API with the following Firebase function code using the node.js googleapis library
   with server -server authentication using service account
   see node.js client code
   In this code, I have 2 authentication functions
    connect() : to a JSON Web Token
    authorize() : to request an access token from the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server
7. Deployed the Firebase function
8. Run the function
9. Got the JWT client displayed
10. Function ended with error :
    {"infos":"unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."}

**node.js client code**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const {google} = require('googleapis');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const _ = require('lodash');

const KEY = require('./service-key.json');

 function connect () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      KEY.client_email,
      null,
      KEY.private_key,
      _.values(KEY.scopes), // scopes as authorized in G-Suite admin
      KEY.admin_email . // impersonated user
    );
    jwtClient.authorize((err) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(jwtClient); // returns client
      }
    });
  });
}

// Send  a message to the contact user 
function sendMessage (client, sender, msg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: KEY.admin_email,
        serviceClient: KEY.client_id,
        privateKey: KEY.private_key,
        accessToken: client.access_token,
        refreshToken: client.refresh_token,
        expires: client.expiry_date
      }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'SITE CONTACT<' + sender + '>',
      to: KEY.contact_email,
      subject: 'Message',
      text: 'From: ' + sender + '\n\n' + msg,
      html: '<h1>Message</h1><p>From: ' + sender + '</p><p>' + msg + '</p>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(response);
    });

  });
}

function newContactMessage (from, msg) {
  return connect()
    .then(client => {
      return sendMessage(client, from, msg);
    });
}

exports.sendContactMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const sender_email = 'dufourisabelle@orange.fr';
  const sender_msg = 'just a test message to contact the site owner.'
  newContactMessage(sender_email, sender_msg).then(() => {
    return {status: 200};
  }, error => {
    return {status: error.status, infos: error.message};
  }).then(response => {
    return res.send(response);
  }).catch(console.error);
});
```

What could I add to it ? I'll try to re-initiate the all process and pray ... ??

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243862

Comment: nope... in this case I am using nodemailer client lib.. but thnaks for the link, I may try to send message directly with gmail lib as described in this question...